# How to replace strings counting commas in a comma-separated string?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a string with 10 comma-separated values and a line break per line. Example:

```
value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10,
value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10,
value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10,
```

I need to remove all columns except column1 and column8 using JavaScript or jQuery. So I think I shoud count commas and use [replace() function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) but I am not sure how to do it.

Then I will use that data for a [line graph of chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can split on the line ending character `\n` and then on the commas in order to filter the wanted columns:

```js
const val =  `value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10,
value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10,
value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10,`

const res = val.split('\n').map(row => row.split(',').filter((v, i) => i == 0 || i == 7));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.split(',')` to get arrays. Then ,`map()` to choose just the coluns you want.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the split function in javascript. It will split the string into an array, in your case with 10 values. You can then join column 1 and 8 for a new string. If you're final result should be value1,value8. Something like:

```js
// loop over lines
  var arr = line.split(",");
  var col2Arr = [arr[0], arr[7]];
  var newStr = col2Arr.join();
  //do what you need to do with newStr
//end loop
```

Answer (score -4):

Here's the code snippet for that:

```js
let string = `value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10,
value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10,
value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10,`;

let res = string.replace(",", "\n");
console.log(res)
```

Comment: How does this remove all columns except "column1" and "column8"?

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.